# Make `hippie-expand` check external file

Tags: hippie-expand

I have a list of technical terms in a file called `jargon.tex` which I want to use with `hippie-expand` in a new project. I do not want to manually load this file every time in a separate buffer when working on a project for `hippie-expand` to find it. Is there a way to write a function to be added in the `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` to always check this file without manually loading it in a separate buffer?